# Why do I get an error when stating my package?

Tags: java

I'm learning Java, and how to use multiple classes. I'm trying to get `Enter your name.` printed on the console, the user says their name, then I print the message `("Hello, ) + name)`.

When I try to run it, I get an error. (`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: at bucky.ParaMain.main(ParaMain.java:7)`).

Below is my code from class 1, named `ParaMain.java`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

package bucky;

public class ParaMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    ParaS secObject = new ParaS();

    System.out.println("Enter your name.");
    String name = input.nextLine();

    secObject.SimpleMessage(name);

}

}
```

Here is my code from the second class, named `ParaS.java`.

```
package bucky;

public class ParaS {
public void SimpleMessage(String name) {
    System.out.println("Hello, " + name);
}
}
```

Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think that package name comes after import statements.

Comment: I just fixed it, thank you.

Comment: Imports should be after package. Package is the first statement in your java file.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comment from Darshan Lila : 
the package declaration MUST be on first line, if present, then imports, then your class ;)

Answer (score 1):

Package declaration goes before imports

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to change where it is. Move the package to before the imports. 
See below:

```
package bucky;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ParaMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        ParaS secObject = new ParaS();

        System.out.println("Enter your name.");
        String name = input.nextLine();

        secObject.SimpleMessage(name);

    }

}
```

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

In a java source file, there should be only one package statement and it should be the first statement in your file.
In class `ParaMain` reverse these statements:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

package bucky;
```

should be the other way round.

```
package bucky;

import java.util.Scanner;
```

Answer (score 0):

Including the Designated Package will resolve the problem
IF you are using Eclipse or Net Beans it will give error suggestion to you press Ctrl+1 to resolve the problem